# iOS programming: customized buttons in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, button, viewdidappear

I created regular buttons in .xib file and I added a gradient effect to them and shadows in the code in this section:

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

```
... my customized buttons code here
```

}

When I modally switch to another view controller and then go back to the original one the xib file gets redrawn but all the gradient effects and shadows disappear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely what's going on, but note that after you dismiss the modal view controller, `viewDidAppear:` gets called again. If you only want to make these buttons once, you could move your custom button code to `viewDidLoad`.

I haven't experienced this problem before to know what's going on, so it would be helpful to see the code itself. But I suspect that moving the code to `viewDidLoad` would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When modal View is dismissed, ViewDidLoad is not called, But ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear is called, But you say that the code is written in ViewDidAppear, and still it doesnt work. I suggest you to write that code in ViewWillAppear and check.